# How to install MaterialDrawer library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I install Material Drawer library I tried use this method but not work

I use File > New > New Module > Import Gradle Project > Select my source directory > Import app/library > Finish
[image]

[image]

[image]

But I still got error

`Error:(9, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments                [com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.8.2@aar, build_baxn3lpydhn6fk3csutsz855j$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure4@dd62d82] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

Do my method is incorrect or just I did wrong?

Comment: I think what you are trying to import is sample of library, give path to the library module inside that project. Alternatively you should use @aar dependency in gradle file if it is provided rather than the module.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this :

file-->New-->Import module

choose your library path and finish.